# Filtering and splitting on position

Tags: c#, ios, linq, xamarin

SO Im stuck with my project while creating some shared code. I have a list containing some strings. I want to filter this and then split the filtered string on position. I already done this in objective-c but I cant figure out how to do this in c#.

Objective-c would be like this:

```
NSPredicate *findStringWithStatusPlanned = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'TOMTOM101'"];
        NSArray *filteredArrayOnStatusPlanned = [trackTraceContentFiltered filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findStringWithStatusPlanned];
        NSLog(@"%@",filteredArrayOnStatusPlanned);

        plannedStatusCompleet = [filteredArrayOnStatusPlanned lastObject];
            janssenRef = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 8)];
            clientRef = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, 15)];
            dateReceived = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(25, 10)];
            tomTomCode = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(36, 9)];
            orderText = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(47, 59)];
            podFileName = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(113, 19)];
            Plannedidentifier = [plannedStatusCompleet substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(62, 1)];
            NSLog(@"Planid:%@",Plannedidentifier);

        NSArray *cutContentPlannedStatus = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:janssenRef,clientRef,dateReceived,tomTomCode,orderText,podFileName,Plannedidentifier,nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cutContentPlannedStatus forKey:@"plannedData"];
```

I tryed to split like this:

```
foreach (string s in TrackTraceDataByLine) {
                string[] splitted = s.Split (new char[] { ' ' });
                if (s.Length >= referenceNumber.Length) {
                    if (referenceNumber == splitted [1]) {
                        dataFilteredOnRef.Add (s);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can quickly to the realization that I have to do it by position rather then splitting on spaces. This is because some parts like the reference number can contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
var janssenRef = sourceString.Substring(0, 8);
var clientRef = sourceString.Substring(9, 15);
var dateReceived = sourceString.Substring(25, 10);
...
var array = new string[] { ... };
```

To do this in a Linq style you could use a jagged array:

```
var pos = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 0, 8 }, 
    new int[] { 9, 15 }, 
    new int[] { 25, 10 }, ... };
var array = pos.Select(p => sourceString.Substring(p[0], p[1]))
               .ToArray();
```

Or a multidimensional array:

```
var pos = new int[,] { { 0, 8 }, { 9, 15 }, { 25, 10 }, ... };
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, pos.GetLength(0))
                      .Select(i => inputString.Substring(pos[i,0], pos[i,1]))
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Going to try this tomorrow but it looks good!:).

Comment: `{ 0, 3 }` should be `{ 0, 8 }` but great solution!

Comment: Error CS0623: Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead (CS0623) (TrackandTrace.IOS)

Comment: @user1805901 It seems C# doesn't support jagged array initialization. I've updated my answer.